# Which method is called at each stage in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am a beginner with recyclerview , below is the default implementation of an adapter class in my recyclerview. I know the basic fundamental function of what the recyclerview does , but I am not sure how the entire flow works.

From the below implemented methods , Which methods  are called at each stage of the recycling process & what do these functions do ?

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
private int[] colorArray = new int[]{android.R.color.black, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
        android.R.color.holo_green_dark, android.R.color.holo_red_dark};

ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> data, ViewPager2 viewPager2) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
    this.viewPager2 = viewPager2;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String animal = mData.get(position);
    holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(colorArray[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView myTextView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Button button;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnToggle);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (viewPager2.getOrientation() == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL)
                    viewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
                else {
                    viewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
                }
            }
        });
    }}}
```

Comment: I'd say, try it out yourself! Add logging functions to each call, open your app and scroll through it and see which calls are made when!

Answer (score 0):

- onCreateViewHolder: This is used to inflate the custom xml layout you have created to display each row of the recycler view.
- onBindViewHolder: This method binds your data to each row. This is where you set textviews, imageviews and others to each item in your list of data.
- getItemCount: This tells recycler view the total number of items in your list of data.
- ViewHolder class: This is the class where you get reference to Id of views in your xml layout file like you normally get them in activities and then set listeners to the views and do whatever you want with the views.